# I'm having problems reloading the page data and losing my images Error Appearing in console net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR Everybody helped me with

Tags: javascript, laravel, https, laravel-8

I'm having problems reloading the page data and losing my images Error Appearing in console net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR Everybody helped me with   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu1k1.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, have same issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70928682/how-to-solve-chrome-only-err-http2-protocol-error-with-loading-images-20 .
Nobody know answer :/ new chrome (jan 2022+) is broken and cant load images from some hostings/cdns with unknown reason. I "parially" solved that by catching image fail event and try to reload it several times .