# How to solve chrome only - ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR - with loading images. ? (2022)

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome

This started happening only in last few days (january 2022) and only in chrome (for example 97.0.4692.99 (Official Build) (64-bit)). If I have 10+ images on page, chrome will randomly fail to download some, with only this as reason :
**(failed)net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR**

Its random, after refresh it wont download other images that loaded just ok before, or it download all.

I am asking on this because there seems to be no fresh info on this error, only similar questions asked several years ago which not really covering this case .

Anybody have some advice ?

Tnx all for help!

---

EDIT : Some time passed, I used JS which watch if image fail to load and if yes then try to reload it 5 times max, while doing queue if more images encounter that on same time .. ugly but works.

Comment: Just additional info, use letsencrypt at page hosting. And got about 30+ reports from users about images not loading randomly all in chrome on windows or android , all started recently. Asked at hosting if hardisk was not full, it was not. So still no idea what could be source of problem or how to solve this. If I click on image with mouse and pick - reload image, it will load.

Comment: Was going through it with server support, but they had no idea what to do about this, seems like latest chrome version is just broken.

Comment: Since issue is still on, and hosting tech has no idea what is happening, posted also in there https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/149228416/97-0-4692-99-chrome-fail-to-load-images?hl=en

Comment: Some new interesting info is that, this happens only for larger images. Meaning if I load 10 images with resolution is about 720x9000, some of them will fail. But If I load 10 images 720x1900 all loads good even if I go in pagination and browse like 100 of them

Comment: Since few months passed with no solution, I advice our users to simply not use chrome because its broken.

Comment: Some time passed, I used JS which watch if image fail to load and if yes then try to reload it 5 times max, while doing queue if more images encounter that on same time .. ugly but works.